# Prevent CSRF Attack for PUT and Delete request ASP.NET Web API

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security, asp.net-web-api, csrf

Does ValidateAntiForgeryToken work for PUT and Delete Requests or only for post request in ASP.NET Web API? If not, What is the best way to make it secure?

Answer (score 5):

Anti CSRF is usually done by matching tokens from both cookie and body to validate the request in non-ajax call like browser form post.

In an ajax call, it's recommended to put a token in custom header. If you installed latest [ASP.NET 2012.2 update](http://www.asp.net/vnext). It has a spa template in MVC project dialog, which demonstrates how to prevent CSRF in a SPA app. Here is the code copied from the template to validate header token from server side.

```
public class ValidateHttpAntiForgeryTokenAttribute : AuthorizationFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        HttpRequestMessage request = actionContext.ControllerContext.Request;

        try
        {
            if (IsAjaxRequest(request))
            {
                ValidateRequestHeader(request);
            }
            else
            {
                AntiForgery.Validate();
            }
        }
        catch (HttpAntiForgeryException e)
        {
            actionContext.Response = request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden, e);
        }
    }

    private bool IsAjaxRequest(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        IEnumerable<string> xRequestedWithHeaders;
        if (request.Headers.TryGetValues("X-Requested-With", out xRequestedWithHeaders))
        {
            string headerValue = xRequestedWithHeaders.FirstOrDefault();
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(headerValue))
            {
                return String.Equals(headerValue, "XMLHttpRequest", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    private void ValidateRequestHeader(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        string cookieToken = String.Empty;
        string formToken = String.Empty;

        IEnumerable<string> tokenHeaders;
        if (request.Headers.TryGetValues("RequestVerificationToken", out tokenHeaders))
        {
            string tokenValue = tokenHeaders.FirstOrDefault();
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(tokenValue))
            {
                string[] tokens = tokenValue.Split(':');
                if (tokens.Length == 2)
                {
                    cookieToken = tokens[0].Trim();
                    formToken = tokens[1].Trim();
                }
            }
        }

        AntiForgery.Validate(cookieToken, formToken);
    }
}
```

From the client side, you also need to set the header in ajax call. This is code from todo.datacontext.js:

```
function ajaxRequest(type, url, data, dataType) { // Ajax helper
    var options = {
        dataType: dataType || "json",
        contentType: "application/json",
        cache: false,
        type: type,
        data: data ? data.toJson() : null
    };
    var antiForgeryToken = $("#antiForgeryToken").val();
    if (antiForgeryToken) {
        options.headers = {
            'RequestVerificationToken': antiForgeryToken
        }
    }
    return $.ajax(url, options);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an action filter class to handle the validation of the anti forgery tokens..

```
public class WebApiValidateJsonToken : System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext filterContext)
    {
        //get the base url or virtual directory of web app
        var virtualDirectory = filterContext.Request.Headers.GetValues("vd").First();

        //base 64 encode the virtual directory
        var encodedVirtualDirectory = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(virtualDirectory));

        //set cookie name to look for to append '_' + base 64 encoded virtual directory to match how Asp.Net Html.AntiforgeryToken 
        //names the cookie that holds the token
        var cookieName = "__RequestVerificationToken" + (String.IsNullOrEmpty(encodedVirtualDirectory) ? "" : "_" + ReplacePadding(encodedVirtualDirectory));

        //get the formtoken created by the Html.AntiforgeryToken helper (hidden input element in view) value sent in ajax header
        var formtoken = filterContext.Request.Headers.GetValues("antiForgeryToken").First();

        //get the cookie token value with the name generated from above
        var cookietoken = filterContext.Request.Headers.GetCookies(cookieName).FirstOrDefault()[cookieName].Value;


        try
        {
            //Validate antiforgery token the old way because can't use ValidateAntiforgeryToken attribute with JSON content
            System.Web.Helpers.AntiForgery.Validate(cookietoken, formtoken);
            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        }
        catch
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("CSRF");
        }


    }

    //Supporting Method to strip base 64 '=' padding and replace with the number representation of padding
    public string ReplacePadding(string b64)
    {
        var count = b64.Count(x => x == '=');
        b64 = b64.Substring(0, b64.Length - count);
        return b64 + count.ToString();
    }
}
```

Here is how I implement it in the view:

```
baseUrl = '@Url.Content("~/")';

        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                antiForgeryToken: $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val(),
                vd: baseUrl.substring(0, baseUrl.length - 1)
            }
        });



                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Content("~/api/WebApiAction")',
                    data: JSON.stringify(paramObject),
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    type: 'PUT'
                })
                .done(function (data) {/*do stuff*/});
```